# Newbie: Decision Tree in R with Two classes(Yes/No) where one class (No) is much larger than other class (Yes)

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am trying to make a decision tree using 4 features (A,B,C,D) to predict an out come for two classes E(Yes, NO). The problem is that the number of observations in my dataset that belong to one class , lets say "No" is much larger (98 times more) than those belong to other class. As a result the accuracy reported by decision tree is around 98% despite the fact that 90% of prediction for class "Yes" is error.

Any idea how to solve this (.e.g force underlying decision tree ("rpart", "ctree"....) to consider accuracy of "yes" class and provides better accuracy?

Comment: Are you willing to use logistic regression?

Answer (score 1):

You can try oversampling or undersampling while data preparation and then split the data into testing and validation samples for building the decision tree.

Answer (score 0):

- Imbalanced data is essentially a cost sensitive training problem. Thus any cost sensitive approach is applicable to imbalanced data. There are many approaches. Undersampling the majority class is a common approach. There are concerns that it is not sample efficient, you are wasting many observations, but the importance of this limitations depends on your sample size.
- You can also specify a cost matrix - or loss matrix is the terminology they use - (cost of False Negatives/False Positives) in *rpart*.